# Logic behind numpy element wise multiplication between 1d array and 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays a and b, a with shape (1000, ) and b with shape (1000, 1)

```
a = np.sin(x) 
b = np.cos(x[:, np.newaxis])
```

Could anyone explain to me the reason why if i do element wise multiplication

```
c = a * b
```

I get that c has shape (1000, 1000)?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy has the concept of broadcasting. It means that that if an axis shape is 1, then it can match another array with a different size, and the element of that axis will be broadcast to all the elements of the other array.

That what happens when you do:

```
x = np.zeros((1,))
y = np.zeros((100,))

x+y
```

Now, there is also the concept of automatic broadcasting. This means that a shape of `(n,)` is also understood as `(1,n)`.

So now in your case, you have this automatic broadcast for `a` happening, meaning that you are multiplying size `(1,1000)` by size `(1000,1)` which are both broadcast through the first broadcast rule, hence giving a result of size `(1000,1000)`.

Comment: Might be better to say `multiplying size (1,1000) by size (1000,1)`